# Fallo en la vista del login con Laravel 8 jetstream

Tags: laravel, laravel-jetstream

Tengo disponibles los controladores, vistas, etc, para realizar la autenticación en Laravel

es un proyecto nuevo

Pero cuando cargo la vista principal no se ve correctamente, así es cómo se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ejecutaste la instalación de dependencias con npm?

Comment: efectivamente, de igual manera sigue sucediendo

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo `guest.blade.php` ubicado en `resources/views/layouts` le debes modificar la manera en la cual está apuntado el archivo css, se encuentra con mix, lo cambias por `asset` y te debería funcionar.

Comment: Un ejemplo concreto sería más claro.

Answer (score 0):

debes borrar vit si es que no trabajaras con el y poner las lineas.

Ejemplo del código:

```
{{-- @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']) --}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
```

Y al final del
body

```
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" ></script>
```

php artisan optmize:clear

npm run dev